# If an allrounder takes highest wickets and scores highest runs then which cap he will be awarded with?

Tags: cricket, awards, indian-premier-league

In IPL, Orange and Purple caps are awarded to the highest run scorer and highest wicket taker.

My question is, if an all-rounder takes highest wickets and scores highest runs then which cap he will be awarded with?

Answer (score -1):

> The Orange Cap is awarded to the top run-scorer in the IPL during a
>   season. It is an ongoing competition with the leader wearing the cap
>   throughout the tournament until the final game, with the eventual
>   winner keeping the cap for the season.
>
> The Purple Cap is awarded to the top wicket-taker in the IPL. It is an
>   ongoing competition with the leader wearing the cap throughout the
>   tournament until the final game, with the eventual winner keeping the
>   cap for the season

courtesy Wikipedia

If your doubt is **what will he wear while playing if he has both?** then no idea,Its not specifically explained anywhere. may we can logically say he will wear orange helmet while batting and wear purple cap while bowling[Its never happend before and very least change to get happen]. 
Or if you are bothered about the cap holder, then 
He will get both caps and hold for that season.
He will surely get the **GOLDEN PLAYER AWARD** too..

[The IPL introduced the Most Valuable Player rating system in 2013, the leader of which would be named the "Most Valuable Player" at the end of the season.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indian_Premier_League_awards)

Comment: why? negative..